# Error accessing picamera in Docker container running on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, docker, raspberry-pi, picamera

I'm running a Docker container using `docker-compose` on Raspberry Pi 4 and would like to use the `picamera` module in Python to access a PiHQCam. I tried to get it to work using this tutorial: https://www.losant.com/blog/how-to-access-the-raspberry-pi-camera-in-docker. However, when trying to build the image, it gave me this error:

```
ValueError: This system does not appear to be a Raspberry Pi
```

I then tried my own solution (see below), but met this error:

```
picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError: Failed to create MMAL component b'vc.camera_info': I/O error
```

Here's my setup:

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yml
version: '3.8'

services: 
  camera:
    build: camera
    image: eye_camera     
    devices:
      - /dev/vchiq
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM balenalib/rpi-raspbian:latest

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade && \
    apt-get install -y python3 \
      python3-pip

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

RUN groupadd -r -g 888 app && \
    useradd -r -u 888 -g app -d /app app && \
    chown -R app:app /app && \
    usermod -a -G video app
USER app

CMD ["python3", "./main.py"]
```

`main.py`:

```py
import picamera

def main():
    print("Hello World!")

    cam = picamera.PiCamera()
    img = picamera.array.PiRGBArray(cam)
    cam.capture(img)
    cam.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The `PiCameraMMALError` occurs right when initialising the camera. This is the full error output:

```
camera_1 | Hello World!
camera_1 | Traceback (most recent call last):
camera_1 |   File "main.py", line 19, in <module>
camera_1 |     main()
camera_1 |   File "main.py", line 12, in main
camera_1 |     cam = picamera.PiCamera()
camera_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 367, in __init__
camera_1 |     with mo.MMALCameraInfo() as camera_info:
camera_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 2346, in __init__
camera_1 |     super(MMALCameraInfo, self).__init__()
camera_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 633, in __init__
camera_1 |     prefix="Failed to create MMAL component %s" % self.component_type)
camera_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/picamera/exc.py", line 184, in mmal_check
camera_1 |     raise PiCameraMMALError(status, prefix)
camera_1 | picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError: Failed to create MMAL component b'vc.camera_info': I/O error
camera_1 | mmal: mmal_vc_shm_init: could not initialize vc shared memory service
camera_1 | mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to initialise shm for 'vc.camera_info' (7:EIO)
camera_1 | mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.camera_info' (7)
```

What's the problem here? Thanks for any help! I'll be happy to provide more info :)

Comment: Do you still have the problem? What is in requirements.txt? What is the version of picamera you are trying to install? Also what RPi version do you use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some utterly unfathomable reason you need the magic incantation "READTHEDOCS=True" to avoid this problem! The following Dockerfile works fine on a Raspberry Pi 4 with it, but without it the Docker image build fails with the error you are seeing :

```
FROM arm32v7/python:latest

# Set in container
ENV TZ=Europe/London

# See https://github.com/waveform80/picamera/issues/578
ENV READTHEDOCS=True

COPY ./src /app    

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

RUN pip install picamera

VOLUME ["/data"]

CMD ["/usr/bin/python", "camera.py"]
```

I built this with the `docker build` command :

```
docker build -t jrcamera:latest .
```

and ran it with the `docker run` command :

```
docker run --privileged=true -v /opt/vc:/opt/vc --env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/vc/lib --device /dev/vchiq -it jrcamera:latest
```

and it ran a treat with the following python script, camera.py, in the src directory (copied to /app in the Docker image) :

```
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
from picamera import PiCamera

camera = PiCamera()

camera.resolution = (1280, 720)

camera.annotate_text_size = 16  # Can be in range 6 to 160 inclusive, with default 32

MAX_ITER = 5

for iter_no in range(0,MAX_ITER):

    camera.start_preview()

    #  It is important to sleep for at least two seconds before capturing an image,
    #  because this gives the cameras sensor time to sense the light levels
    #
    sleep(3)

    # Annotate image with current datetime, to nearest millisecond
    #
    date_time = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.%f')[:-3]

    camera.annotate_text = date_time

    camera.capture("/data/image_{0:}.jpg".format(date_time))

    camera.stop_preview()
```

(Now I just have to figure out how to reduce my image size for this from a ridiculously large 710 MBytes, but that is another problem.)

Comment: Thanks! for me it was just `-v /opt/vc:/opt/vc --env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/vc/lib` that saved the day. I'm still curious on why this is, it definitely used to work by just using --privileged